# Reordering of the class members in clang and g++

Tags: c++, g++, clang

The program

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int T;

struct A
{
    typedef char T;
    T i;
};

int main(){ }
```

should have been ill-formed, because `N4296::3.3.7/5 [basic.scope.class]`:

> If reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid
>   program under (1) and (2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic is
>   required.

But both clang and g++ compile it well

**[G++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8a6119dfe85f167)**

[**CLANG**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c406edeaa049e0c4)

Is it their bug?

Comment: "no diagnostic is required". "no diagnostic is required". "no diagnostic is required".

Answer (score 0):

> If reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid
>   program **under (1) and (2)**, the program is ill-formed, no
>   diagnostic is required.

Despite the removal of this exact (superfluous) bullet point due to [CWG issue #1875](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1875), note the bolded part; If we reorder the declarations

```
struct A
{
    T i;
    typedef char T;
};
```

The program is not conforming to rule 2):

> 2) A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration
>   in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of `S`. No
>   diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

`T` is used in the declaration of `i`, where it refers to the global `typedef`. However, when reevaluated in the completed scope of `A`, `T` refers to the member typedef, which is clearly a different declaration.
This rule is not violated by your code, though.

The standard gives an example to show the difference between my first snippet and yours, and their validity. [basic.scope.class]/5:

```
typedef char* T;
struct Y {
    T a;             // error: T refers to ::T
                     // but when reevaluated is Y::T
    typedef long T;
    T b;
};
```

Thus the code in your question is indeed well-formed.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Both codes are ill-formed (no diagnostic is required)

Comment: @Belloc I cannot see why. The name `T` used does refer to the same name in both named evaluations of bullet point 2. Also consider the example added.

Comment: @Columbo You're right. But the reason why the OP's code is not in error is because what used to be item (3) in [basic.scope.class]/1 was eliminated from the standard. I've just realized this change in N4527.

Comment: @Belloc .. That bullet item was *superfluous*. Have you read my answer?